# A question from Hamilton's Ricci Flow book by bennett chow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On page 3 of the book before exercise 1.2, has written: "torsion free is a compatibility condition with the differentiable structure".
I correctly do not understand how torsion-free condition results compatibility with differentiable structure?. Please help me understand it.

Comment: I don't have the book here with me but if that's what it says it's not really true.  Being torsion-free is basically just a "normalization" condition for a connection.  Every connection has a unique torsion-free replacement that has the same geodesics.  From this perspective connections with torsion simply look like a "rotating reference frame" compared to the torsion-free connection.

Comment: @RyanBudney: I like that perspective. But couldn't one say that being torsion-free is a compatibility condition in the sense that it makes $XY = YX$ imply $\nabla_XY = \nabla_YX$?

Comment: The problem with that interpretation is that a connection is already "compatible" with the differentiable structure in the sense that the connection is itself a smooth function.   So being torsion-free is much more specific than just compatibility.  From the point of view you're pushing it might be better to say "being torsion free allows a convenient computation of the lie bracket".

Comment: retagged since this question is not specifically about the Ricci flow, but about Riemannian/differential geometry in general.